# how to install angular2-multiselect-dropdown specific version

Tags: angular10

Hello I want to install angular2-multiselect-dropdown ^4.6.6 version. I have searched It  in google  but  there was no information about it.  Thank you.

P.S.  sorry  there was not **angular2-multiselect-dropdown** tag  in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try,

```
npm install angular2-multiselect-dropdown@4.6.6
```

You can also look here for more info about `angular2-multiselect-dropdown`

- https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown#readme